# Building URL for CSS Behavior

Tags: url, css, behavior

I am using CSS3Pie in my my website to allow rounded corners in older versions of IE.  In my CSS class I need to add the `behavior` propery to my CSS class

```
#myclass
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(pie.htc)
}
```

It works great for any page that is on the root level of the web site.  When I browse to any sub directory in my site that uses that class, it does not apply the rounded corners cause the pie.htc is in the root of the side.  The behavior URL is relative to the HTML page, not the CSS stylesheet.

How can I build an URL for the `behavior` that makes it accessible to all levels in my web site?

Comment: Have you tried:   url(/pie.htc)

Comment: What directory are the `.css` and `.htc` files in? Do you have a `<base>` element on the page?

Comment: @David - I have tried `/pie.htc` and the class is not applied on either pages on the root or in sub directorys

Comment: @andyb - The `.css` in in a directory outside of the website and the `.htc` is in the root of the website.  I do not have a `<base>` element on my page

Comment: I usually put and external files that CSS rules use (images, fonts, etc...) in the same directory as the `.css` file as `url`s are relative to the source of the `.css` itself. So there would be no need for any leading `/` or path.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing it from an absolute path should work? http://www.domain.com/youknowwhat
Still strange it is relative to the HTML though, you'd think it'd be relative to the CSS file.

Comment: that will not work because I have site on multiple environments (development, staging and production) that have different URLs